# How do I keep the Spotify Android app from hogging all free space for its cache?

Tags: applications, spotify

The Spotify for Android app uses every last byte of space it can find on my device for its cache, and I frequently have to delete `/storage/self/primary/Android/data/com.spotify.music/files/spotifycache/Storage` to reclaim the space. The last time I did it was about a month ago, and now it's 11GB again (12GB available space in total on that device)

I pay for Spotify and would very much rather not serve as their CDN so they can save a few cents on bandwidth while rendering my device unusable.

How can I prevent Spotify from writing to that directory altogether? I tried changing the permissions to 400 but the app fixes the permission and promptly resumes eating up all free space.